# IOS get object from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nsarray

I am developing an IOS application. How can I get the object from NSArray list. What is the best way to avoid getting memory error? Can you tell me the correct method? Thanks

## Recommendation 1

```
Person *person = [[[Person alloc] init] autorelease];
        person = [self.userFavourites objectAtIndex:0];
```

## Recommendation 2

```
Person *person = [self.userFavourites objectAtIndex:0];
[person retain];

//Make the required action

[person release];
```

## Recommendation 3

## ?

Comment: Recommendation 3: start using ARC

Comment: why you are not using ARC i.e. automatic reference counting?

Comment: I dont wat to use ARC now :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Person *person = [self.userFavourites objectAtIndex:0];
```

the `userFavourites` array retains all elements inside and when you get an element it comes autoreleased.

EDIT:
**Recommendation 1** - makes no sense to alloc init autorelease a **Person** object and then get different person from the array.
**Recommendation 2** - you don't need to retain the object, as the array retains it. You only need to retain it if you need it outside your scope

Comment: Although recommendation 2 must be correct; he could call code that modifies that array and removes the object he's using.

Comment: And yet, he would have an autoreleased object until the end of the scope. Autoreleased objects are not like the weak references and they would not nullify once the array looses the strong pointer to the object. So in recommendation 2 retain/release on this particular pointer is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Recommendation 3:

Use ARC and modern objective-c so you write less code:

```
Person *person = self.userFavourites[0];
```

Comment: The OP has stated he doesn't want to use ARC and he's not legally obliged to do so.

Comment: He can use modern objective-c syntax though.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use ARC? It makes your life easier...

However, I would go with recommendation 1, as the autorelease knows how to handle the objects, and it shouldn't give a memory error.

Any more help?

Comment: So go with the option that allocates a new object and then immediately reassigns the pointer to the object with another object?

Comment: If I use recommendation 1 then XCode analyzer show this message "Value stored to 'person' during initialization is never read"

Comment: Because you didn't continue your code, where you actually use your object.. Just continue and hopefully it disappear... Did it? :)

Comment: @trojanfoe is right. alloc init creates a new object. Then you assign another object to the same pointer... no sense at all.

Comment: @Mr_bem Actually I use this object next line NSString *queryParams=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"params=%@&",[Helper getFPersonJson:person]];